# Bidirectional Communication without cookies and sid in URL in flask

Tags: python, flask, browser, flask-socketio, bidirectional

I am trying to find a way to establish a bidirectional communication for a Server-Client architecture without using cookies and without the sessionId being send in the URL.
Flask-SocketIO e.g. unfortunately does both.

Maybe there is a way to send the sessionID as a POST?

Any help would be awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use other storage in the browser to store the session ID. For example, you can use LocalStorage. To use LocalStorage is quite simple, and the following example from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) should explain the usage clearly

```
localStorage = window.localStorage;
localStorage.setItem('myCat', 'Tom');
var cat = localStorage.getItem('myCat');
localStorage.removeItem('myCat');
// clear all items
localStorage.clear();
```

and every other thing should be normal as long as you use JavaScript to manually send the session ID to the flask server.

To send the session ID to the browser for the first time the user login, you can include it in the response header or in the meta tag of the webpage and let your JavaScript to retrieve it and store it.

To let Flask-login stop sending the session ID in the cookie and send them in meta instead, you have to write your own session interface. Fortunately, the [Flask's code](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/024f0d384cf5bb65c76ac59f8ddce464b2dc2ca1/src/flask/sessions.py) is pretty clear and you can refer it to create your own. Just inherent `SessionInterface` and implement your `save_session` and `open_session` methods. after you are done you can use `app.session_interface = YourSessionInterface()` to switch Flask's session engine to yours and then init your `LoginManager` and other stuff. Hope this will give you some thought.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense but unfortunately this is way beyond my skills :/ I looked into the docs. All I see is the word 'cookie'. I have no idea how to get around them :/ On top of that I have no idea how I would create a suitable 'open_session' and 'save_session' function. I don't even understand what the 'open_session' and  'save_session' functions do in the class 'SecureCookieSessionInterface(SessionInterface)'

Comment: @user13799516 Basically, `open_session` retrieves the session from the `request` object, and `save_session` modifies the `response` object to add a session ID in it :).